# boost asio "vector iterator not dereferenceable"

Tags: c++, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I've put together an asynchronous UDP client (code below) which is throwing the error "vector iterator not dereferenceable" after about 4 seconds of running. There appears to be little information on the exact cause of this error within the boost asio context but it would seem that it may be due to a buffer going out of scope.

I'm using shared pointers and I can't see anywhere that would allow them to go out of scope.

Call stack:

```
std::_Debug_message(const wchar_t * message, const wchar_t * file, unsigned int line) Line 15   C++
std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<unsigned char> > >::operator*() Line 72 C++
std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<unsigned char> > >::operator*() Line 325  C++
boost::asio::detail::buffer_debug_check<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<unsigned char> > > >::operator()() Line 532   C++
[External Code] 
boost::asio::detail::buffer_cast_helper(const boost::asio::mutable_buffer & b) Line 146 C++
boost::asio::buffer_cast<void const *>(const boost::asio::mutable_buffer & b) Line 427  C++
boost::asio::detail::buffer_sequence_adapter<boost::asio::const_buffer,boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1>::validate(const boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 & buffer_sequence) Line 207   C++
boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_send_op<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf2<void,client_t,boost::system::error_code const &,unsigned int>,boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<client_t *>,boost::arg<1>,boost::arg<2> > > >::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service * owner, boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation * base, const boost::system::error_code & result_ec, unsigned int bytes_transferred) Line 70    C++
boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation::complete(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service & owner, const boost::system::error_code & ec, unsigned int bytes_transferred) Line 46   C++
boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::do_one(bool block, boost::system::error_code & ec) Line 406   C++
boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code & ec) Line 164  C++
boost::asio::io_service::run() Line 59  C++
boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int,boost::asio::io_service>::operator()(boost::asio::io_service * p) Line 50 C++
boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boost::asio::io_service *> >::operator()<unsigned int,boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int,boost::asio::io_service>,boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<unsigned int> __formal, boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int,boost::asio::io_service> & f, boost::_bi::list0 & a, long __formal) Line 250 C++
boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned int,boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int,boost::asio::io_service>,boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boost::asio::io_service *> > >::operator()() Line 1223   C++
boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned int,boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int,boost::asio::io_service>,boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boost::asio::io_service *> > > >::run() Line 117  C++
boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function(void * param) Line 303  C++
[External Code]
```

It looks like it's occurring during the 'do_send' function call 'async_send_to' but the shared pointer is stored in sended so I don't know how that could be getting deleted?

And the class:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace posix_time = boost::posix_time;
namespace lockfree = boost::lockfree;

typedef std::vector<uint8_t> msg_t;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<msg_t> spmsg_t;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<asio::io_service::work> pwork_t;
typedef lockfree::spsc_queue<spmsg_t> msg_queue_t;

struct client_t {
    asio::io_service &_svc;
    asio::ip::udp::socket _socket;
    asio::ip::udp::endpoint _ep;
    boost::atomic<bool> _connected;
    boost::atomic<bool> _closing;
    boost::thread _worker;
    pwork_t _work;
    msg_queue_t _send_queue;
    msg_queue_t _recv_queue;
    boost::condition_variable m_cond;
    boost::mutex m_Mutex;

    client_t(asio::io_service &svc_) :_svc(svc_), _send_queue(1024), _recv_queue(1024), _socket(svc_, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), 0)){}

    void init(const std::string ip_, const std::string port_) {
        _closing = false;
        sending = false;
        _connected = true;

        boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver resolver(_svc);
        _ep = *resolver.resolve({ boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), ip_, port_ });

        _work = pwork_t(new asio::io_service::work(_svc));
        _worker.swap(boost::move(boost::thread(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &_svc))));

        _svc.post(boost::bind(&client_t::do_recv, this));
    }

    void destroy() {
        _work.reset();
        _worker.join();

        _send_queue.reset();
        _recv_queue.reset();
    }

    bool is_connected() {
        return !_closing && _connected;
    }

    void disconnect() {
        _closing = true;
    }

    boost::atomic<bool> sending;
    spmsg_t sended;
    void do_send() {
        if (_send_queue.pop(sended)) {
            _socket.async_send_to(asio::buffer(*sended), _ep, boost::bind(&client_t::handle_sended, this, asio::placeholders::error, asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else {
            sending.store(false);
            if (_closing) {
                _socket.shutdown(asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
                _socket.close();

                _send_queue.reset();
                _recv_queue.reset();

                _connected = false;
                _closing = false;
            }       
        }

    }
    void handle_sended(const boost::system::error_code &ec_, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (ec_) {
            sending.store(false);
            printf("%s\n", ec_.message().c_str());
            return;
        }

        do_send();
    }


    spmsg_t recv_msg;
    void do_recv() {
        recv_msg = boost::make_shared<msg_t>(2048);
        _socket.async_receive_from(asio::buffer(recv_msg->data() + 4, 2044), _ep, boost::bind(&client_t::handle_recv, this, asio::placeholders::error, asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    void handle_recv(const boost::system::error_code &ec_, std::size_t bytes_transferred_) {

        if (ec_) {
            printf("%s\n",ec_.message().c_str());
            return;
        }
        *(uint32_t*)recv_msg->data() = bytes_transferred_;
        if (_recv_queue.push(recv_msg)) {

            m_cond.notify_one();

            do_recv();
        }
        else {
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    //spmsg_t get_sended(uint32_t len_) { return spmsg_t(new msg_t(len_ + 4)); }

    bool send(unsigned char* msg, int msgSize) {
        if (!is_connected())
            return false;

        spmsg_t msg_ = spmsg_t(new msg_t(msgSize));
        memcpy(&msg_->data()[0], msg, msgSize);

        if (!_send_queue.push(msg_))
            return false;

        //send_messages();

        return true;
    }
    bool send_messages() {
        if (!is_connected())
            return false;
        static bool f = false;
        if (!sending.compare_exchange_strong(f, true))
            return false;

        _svc.post(boost::bind(&client_t::do_send, this));
    }


    spmsg_t recv() {
        if (!is_connected())
            return NULL;

        spmsg_t recved;
        if (_recv_queue.pop(recved))
            return recved;
        else{
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_Mutex);
            if (m_cond.timed_wait(lock, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000)))
            {
                _recv_queue.pop(recved);
                return recved;
            }
            else
                return NULL;
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: If you can, try running your code under thread- and adress sanitizer under Linux. Your class is using every synchronization primitive known to man, yet you haven't documented any invariants, so I highly suspect a data race and/or other undefined behaviour. Also couldn't some of the code be removed while still reproducing the problem?

Comment: Looks like you are using shared pointers poorly. For example, `spmsg_t recv_msg;` is assigned `recv_msg = boost::make_shared<msg_t>(2048);` then passed off to an asynch call. If I'm not horribly mistaken, this opens up the possibility for another call to `do_recv` to reassign `recv_msg`. Since `recv_msg` is no longer pointing to the earlier `msg_t` and I don't see anywhere the `msg_t` is guaranteed to handed off or shared, that `msg_t` may be deleted before the asynch call is completed.

Comment: do_recv is not called again until handle_sended is called by the async method 'async_receive_from', it will not be running more than once at any given time.